# doctype html causing form input field to be cut off

Tags: html, css, doctype

I noticed a problem on one of my html forms where the text input field was being cut off.  I narrowed down the cause of it to the <!DOCTYPE html> directive that we're using at the top of the page.

When I exclude the <!DOCTYPE html> directive, the inputs in the scenario below render correctly, meaning that the text input field is drawn in its entirety.  But when I load this snippet as is (with <!DOCTYPE html>), the right side of the text input is cut off.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?  I notice this problem in IE9, Firefox 23 and Chrome 29.

Here's the snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#testDiv span {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
#testInput {
    width: 100%;
}
#testButton {
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="testForm" method="post">
        <div id="testDiv"> 
            <button id="testButton">Apply</button>             
            <span><input type="text" id="testInput" /></span>
        </div>
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: box-sizing + quirkMode ?

Comment: Look very closely at the right side of the text input field.  It looks different (the right border is cut off) when the doctype tag is present, vs when it's removed.  The difference is subtle - you might need to have the two side-by-side to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer lies in the differences between HTML4 and HTML5, specifically the CSS box-sizing (-moz-box-sizing, -webkit-box-sizing) property.  In HTML4, the box-sizing property defaults to "border-box".  In HTML5, the box-sizing property defaults to "content-box".

border-box means that the border and padding are included in the box's width.  content-box means that the border and padding are extra on top of the width of the box.  So where a box would fit nicely between elements in HTML4, its right side border could be cut off in HTML5 because its width does not account for the 1px border.

Solution: add "box-sizing: border-box;" (and related rules for -moz and -webkit) to CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is how the doctype interprets the width:100%, so there's no space left for that right border.  You could change it to width:99.9%, if that would meet your needs.